# VBA Excel - Range in Variant split by content criteria

Tags: excel, vba, variant

I have a very large data block in an excel spreadsheet (100,000 rows by 30 columns).

The first column can have one of only six different values (CAT1..CAT6).

I need to split the content in 6 spreadsheets in the same book.

I load the source range in a source variant and split it in target variant, which I write in target sheets.

Code is along this lines:
    Sub TestVariant()

```
Dim a, b, c As Variant
Dim i, j, k As Variant

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AD100000").Value

ReDim b(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2))
ReDim c(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2))

j = 1
k = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
Select Case a(i, 1)
    Case "CAT01"
        b(j, 1) = a(i, 1)
        '..
        b(j, 30) = a(i, 30)
        j = j + 1
    Case Else
        c(k, 1) = a(i, 1)
        '..
        c(k, 30) = a(i, 30)
        k = k + 1
    End Select
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)) = b
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(c, 1), UBound(c, 2)) = c

End Sub
```

Now for the questions:

- Is there a way to copy one "row" at a time from the source variant to the target variant? Something like

  b(j,) = a(i,)
- Is there a way to simply redim the target variants to the data content (initially I just DIM to match the source but each target variant will obiously have less content than the source
- Is there any other approach to the split problem more efficient? (collections? keys?)

Any suggestions will be most appreciated.

Thanks for reading

Cris

Comment: you could use `Filter` , just filter the entire data by "CAT" in Column A, and then copy the entire Filtered Range to another worksheet, that is the fastest and easiset approcah will large collection of data

Comment: copying range to range seems to take a long time (hours!)

Comment: Loading data in the Variant is incredibly fast.

Comment: have you tried copying range to range , and adding the line `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` ,it's amazing how faster it runs

Comment: I always turn off Screen updates AND calculations, as there are a lot of lookup and matches pointing to the target sheets of the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a combination of [`Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) and [`Autofilter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) methods of `Range` object should be quite fast:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestVariant()
    Dim iCat As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("AD1", .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, 1).End(xlUp))
            .Sort key1:=Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes ', SortMethod:=xlPinYin, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
            For iCat = 1 To 6
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="CAT0" & iCat '<--| filter its columns A on current "CAT"
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1).Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than header
                    With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.COUNT - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        GetWorkSheet("CAT0" & iCat).Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.COUNT, .Columns.COUNT).Value = .Value
                    End With
                End If
            Next iCat
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Function GetWorkSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorkSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetWorkSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetWorkSheet = Worksheets.Add
        GetWorkSheet.name = shtName
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: LOL:) I was wondering how fast you'll come with the answer (that's why I had it in the comments) You are the expert on `AutoFilter`

Comment: @ShaiRado; haha! well everybody has its own beloved toy... But `AutoFilter()` and `Sort()` are really powerful methods so I'm constantly using them. But lets' see Cristian Croitoru feedback.

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I suggested them to him (after reading a few of you previous answer here), and that's why I left it for the Pro to answer :)

Comment: @ShaiRado, thanks for the "Pro". But should I actually be one of those, then you are too!

Comment: why do you have `Criteria1:="CAT0"` shouldn't it be `Criteria1:="CAT"` ? why did you add the `0` at the end ?

Comment: @ShaiRado It's because I saw a `"CAT01"` in OP's code, hence I thought he'd want to use "CAT01", "CAT02", and so on. But it can be set as he needs

Comment: read again carefuly, in his post he wrote `(CAT1..CAT6)` , and his code he uses `CAT01` so go figure :)

Comment: @ShaiRado, yes I saw that too, but I chose to follow the _coded_ pattern. Anyhow it can be set as needed, just waiting for Cristian Croitoru feedback

Comment: thanks guys, CAT or CAT0 does not make any difference.

Comment: I did not have time to test this solution but I will ASAP

Comment: Using Load from range to variant, select case split in variants and write back to range - 100000x28 = 6s
Using sort+filter+copyrange+paste (as in the above code) - 100000x28 = 5s

Comment: Just to clarify that my solution does not "copyrange +paste" while it uses "Range.Value" to paste values between ranges. Which is faster then "copyrange+paste". What solution did you test?

Comment: I stand corrected, I meant copy values from one range to the other. I pretty much used your full code. Note that the initial row by row Select Case and row range value source to target copy was not finished after 1 hour so I gave up on timing that one.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort @user3598756